# Stopping a recurrence of a corrupt windows 10 profile

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

On my laptop I keep getting a recurring problem. I turn it on and it shouts at me that login service have failed and it logs me into a fresh default profile.

This is a reasonably common problem, lots of q&a out there about it. It worried me at first but now frankly I'm used to it, I can almost remember how to fix it without checking again online- go into regedit, find the user profiles, change the state of your broken one to 0, delete the temp folder with the same number, delete bak from the end of your profile name, reboot and bam, good as new.

Yet it keeps happening. Clearly what I'm doing here is not fixing the root of the problem, just constantly sticking a new bit of tape on whenever it falls down.

Just what could be causing constant windows profile corruptions?- is there anyway to find this out?

And what can be done to stop it happening?

Answer (score 0):

> On my laptop I keep getting a recurring problem. I turn it on and it
> shouts at me that login service have failed and it logs me into a
> fresh default profile.

The only sure fix for this is a new User Profile.

Log on, back up all your documents, email and data.

Make a new, Admin, User Account.

Log into the new Admin account, Delete your existing account and user profile, restart, make a new Account for yourself (it can be the same account name having deleted the old profile).

Log into the new account and restore your documents.

Two things:

1. Be certain of your backups because you are going to delete your existing account and profile.  Double check your steps and work carefully.
2. Use a neutral location (c:\temp) for storing your documents and recovering them from a new user.